# War das Deutsch des 18., 19. und frühen 20. Jahrhunderts präziser, ausdrucksstärker und wortgewaltiger als das heutige?

Tags: vocabulary, history, anglicism, writing, evolution

Wenn ich Werke aus dieser Zeit lese, egal ob sie nun literarischer, philosophischer oder wissenschaftlicher Natur sind, fällt mir dabei nicht nur auf, dass sie aufgrund der damals noch international vorherrschenden Rolle der deutschen Sprache in diesen Bereichen „reiner“ verfasst und nicht mit vielen Anglizismen und ähnlichem versehen worden sind, sondern auch, dass sie virtuoser mit Worten und der vokabularen und grammatikalischen Vielfalt der deutschen Sprache umgegangen sind, als dies in späterer Zeit (ungefähr ab 1950 bis heute) der Fall war. Über die Umgangssprache der damaligen Zeit vermag ich nichts zu sagen, außer dass sie sich vom geschriebenen Wort, früher wie heute, unterschieden hat, doch vermute ich, dass das Deutsch, das damals gesprochen wurde, ebenfalls diese Merkmale aufwies, auf verschiedene Weise zwar in den einzelnen sozialen Schichten einer Gesellschaft, sie aber dennoch in ihrer Gänze durchdringend.

Würde man, so vermute ich, einem (gebildeten) Menschen, der mit dem Deutsch großgeworden ist, das man in diesem Zeitraum in Wort und Schrift verwendete, einen im heutigen Deutsch verfassten Text vorlegen, der keine Anglizismen und ähnliches enthält, würde er wohl trotzdem eine Verkümmerung der Sprache feststellen, die sich in vielen Wortwiederholungen und eintönigen Satzformulierungen ergeht anstatt sich der Vielfalt zu bedienen, die die deutsche Sprache zu bieten hat. Das, was heutzutage teils mit vielen Worten umständlich oder ungelenk mit Anglizismen und teils grammatikalisch nicht korrekten Formulierungen umschrieben wird, würde einem deutschsprachigen Menschen von damals wohl eher als ein Gestammel denn als präziser Ausdruck dessen, was man sagen möchte, vorkommen. Zwar mag es heute noch vereinzelt Autoren in allen Bereichen geben, die diesem kunstvollen und eindrücklichen Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache nicht verlustig gegangen sind, doch scheinen diese heute eher die Ausnahme zu bilden, wohingegen sie früher, so mein Eindruck, eher die Regel waren.

Gab es also innerhalb der letzten 70 Jahre einen Rückschritt im allgemeinen Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache, wohingegen Fortschritte in anderen Bereichen wie der Medizin und Technik erzielt worden sind? Wenn ja: Was sind, neben dem heute weltweiten Vorherrschen der englischen Sprache, die Gründe für diese Entwicklung, die sich nicht alleine auf den Einfluss des Englischen auf das Deutsche zurückführen lassen und wie könnte diesen entgegengewirkt werden?

Comment: Der Meinung kann man natürlich sein. Aber Sprachen entwickeln sich und viel in Bezug auf weltweite Verständigung wurde gewonnen. Englisch ist nun mal die Sprache dieser Zeit und wer in den Natur- und Ingenierurswissenschaften gelesen werden will publiziert auf Englisch oder wird ignoriert. Und für manche (viele) Begriffe gibt es einfach kein gutes deutsches Wort. Andererseits wurden deutsche Worte ins englische integriert (z. B. in den Geowissenschaften). Ich vermute das wir das hier nicht klären können. Aber lasse mich auch gerne belehren.

Comment: Übrigens, bin gebürtiger Deutscher, lebe in Spanien und mein täglicher Umgang ist englisch. Da kommt mir die Frage doch recht kleinlich vor.

Comment: Oh nein, die Verkümmerung der **Deutschen Sprache** ™. Jeder der so argumentiert, sollte auf Protogermanisch schreiben, meiner Meinung nach.

Comment: Vielleicht ist es selektive Wahrnehmung: Schließlich müsste für einen validen Vergleich schonmal querbeet über alle (literarischen) Bereiche und Einkommensklassen das Schriftwerk verglichen werden. Also nicht nur die "Klassiker", die heute noch empfohlen werden, sondern alles,bis runter zum Schund. Mit den Klassikern von heute (was man in 100 Jahren weiß) und dem Schund. Und dann gibt es so Effekte wie: da kamen Zeitungen hinzu, da kam Radio, Fernsehen, Internet hinzu - allein das Schriftvolumen und Sender/Empfänger wurden ein anderen Publikum.

Comment: Facebook/ Twitter schreiben verhunzt Sprache? Früher sah das keiner. Dafür schreiben die Leute heute, früher hätten sie das nie. Auch wenn "Sprachnachrichten" sich wohl aufschwingen, die an gezielte Personen verschickten Kurznachrichten abzulösen. Und die Vorherrschung des Englischen: Mal zurück schauen, wo der Adel Französisch statt Deutsch sprach. Kommt, geht. Chinesisch next big thing?

Comment: "Autoren [...], die diesem kunstvollen und eindrücklichen Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache nicht verlustig gegangen sind" ... Wie poetisch. Ob der Umgand die Autoren, die er verloren hat, wohl vermisst?

Comment: Deine Frage beweist, dass die deutsche Sprache auch heute noch mehr als Gestammel zu bieten hat.

Answer (score 4):

Ich finde die Frage widersprüchlich in sich.

Einerseits sprichst du von der (ehemaligen) *vokabularen und grammatikalischen Vielfalt der deutschen Sprache*, von der *Verkümmerung der Sprache* und einem *Rückschritt im allgemeinen Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache*.

Auf der anderen Seite stellst du selbst fest, dass Aussagen heute *teils mit vielen Worten (…) oder (…) mit Anglizismen und teils grammatikalisch nicht korrekten Formulierungen umschrieben* werden **können** (Präjudizien habe ich entfernt, um den Kern der Aussage freizulegen).

Es ist überhaupt nicht ersichtlich, wie ein Zuwachs an Vielfalt in Grammatik und Vokabular zu einer Verkümmerung führen soll. Insbesondere geht es hier um Tendenzen, die nicht erst "ungefähr ab 1950" eingesetzt haben, sondern entweder universell in Sprachen mit vorhanden sind, deren Sprachraum nicht komplett von der Außenwelt isoliert ist (*Lehnwörter*), oder aber bereits seit dem Althochdeutschen bestehen und somit Teil der Entwicklung hin zu dem Sprachgebrauch sind, den du als Spitze der Entwicklung auffasst (z.B. der *Rückgang synthetischer Formenbildung* – vulgo "mit vielen Worten umständlich ausgedrückt" – im Vergleich zum Ahd. und Mhd., auf den aber dennoch die Zunahme des Prinzips der *Komposition* seit dem 16. Jh. und später der *Pluralmarkierungen am Substantiv* folgte).

Bezüglich deines größten Bedenkens, der Übernahme von Wörtern aus dem Englischen: warum sollte diese dem Deutschen mehr "schaden" als die Übernahme französischer (*beige*, *Café*), polnischer (*Grenze*) oder finnischer (*Sauna*)?